# Getting error "depends on nonexistent group" when running tests from testng.xml

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-eclipse

Below is the structure of my project:

```
Public class first{
    @BeforeSuite(groups="A")
    }

Public class second{
    @Test(groups="B",dependOnGroups="A")
    }
```

testng.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="testSuite" >
 <groups>  
      <run> 
         <include name="A"/> 
         <include name="B"/> 
      </run>  
 </groups>

 <test name="test1" allow-return-values="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.first" />
        </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="test2" allow-return-values="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.second" />
        </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

When I run this as `run testng.xml` I get the error:

> depends on nonexistent group A
> at org.testng.DependencyMap.getMethodsThatBelongTo(DependencyMap.java:41)
> at org.testng.internal.DynamicGraphHelper.createDynamicGraph(DynamicGraphHelper.java:76)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:618)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)

Answer (score 1):

for testng file you need to add the package name for groups and classes, below is an example for groups.

```
 <suite name="testSuite" >
         <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="packagename.first"/>
                <include name="packagename.second"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
  </suite>
```

Comment: that did not help , it just doesnt run anything when i add the package name
`code`
<suite name="testSuite" >
     <groups>  
          <run> 
            <include name="test.A"/> 
             <include name="test.B"/> 
          </run>  
     </groups>
    
     <test name="test1" allow-return-values="true">
            <classes>
                <class name="test.first" />
            </classes>
     </test>
     <test name="test2" allow-return-values="true">
            <classes>
                <class name="test.second" />
            </classes>
     </test>
    </suite>